# Getting DOM element value using pure JavaScript

Tags: javascript, get, element

Is there any **difference** between these solutions?

Solution 1:

```js
function doSomething(id, value) {
  console.log(value);
  //...
}
```

```html
<input id="theId" value="test" onclick="doSomething(this.id, this.value)" />
```

...and Solution 2:

```js
function doSomething(id) {
  var value = document.getElementById(id).value;
  console.log(value);
  //...
}
```

```html
<input id="theId" value="test" onclick="doSomething(this.id)" />
```

Comment: Edit: As several have pointed out, there are a few typos (including the lack of a function name in the javascript), but conceptually, they are the same and either one will work fine.

Comment: The edits, which were made after 3 years made most of the answers here invalid.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

**Update:** The question was edited. Both of the solutions are now equivalent.

#### Original answer

**Yes**, most notably! I don't think the second one will work (and *if it does, not very portably*). The first one should be OK.

```
// HTML:
<input id="theId" value="test" onclick="doSomething(this)" />

// JavaScript:
function(elem){
    var value = elem.value;
    var id    = elem.id;
    ...
}
```

This should also work.

Comment: It goes for element arrays as well. Example: `items[i].id`

Comment: Would you care to explain why you think your answer is what I would want to go with?

Comment: @Barrosy getting the id and then using getElementById is unneccesary when you have a reference to the element already (solution #2). Passing parameters explicitly (solution #1) can sometimes be a good programming practice.

Answer (score 54):

The second function should have:

```
var value = document.getElementById(id).value;
```

Then they are basically the same function.

Answer (score 9):

In the second version, you're passing the String returned from `this.id`. Not the element itself.

So `id.value` won't give you what you want.

You would need to pass the element with `this`.

```
doSomething(this)
```

then:

```
function(el){
    var value = el.value;
    ...
}
```

---

Note: In some browsers, the second one would work if you did:

```
window[id].value
```

because element IDs are a global property, but *this is not safe*.

It makes the most sense to just pass the element with `this` instead of fetching it again with its ID.

Answer (score 7):

Pass the object:

```
doSomething(this)
```

You can get all data from object:

```
function(obj){
    var value = obj.value;
    var id = obj.id;
}
```

Or pass the `id` only:

```
doSomething(this.id)
```

Get the object and after that value:

```
function(id){
    var value = document.getElementById(id).value;  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference if we look on effect - value will be the same. However there is something more...

Solution 3:

```js
function doSomething() {
  console.log( theId.value );
}
```

```html
<input id="theId" value="test" onclick="doSomething()" />
```

if DOM element has id then you can use it in js directly

Answer (score 1):

This should also work.

```js
function doSomething() {
  yourElement = document.getElementById("yourID);
    yourValue = yourElement.value; console.log(yourValue);
    console.log(yourValue);
  }
```

```html
<div id="yourID" value="1" onclick="doSomething()">
</div>
```

```js
function doSomething() {
  console.log( theId.value );
}
```

```html
<input id="theId" value="test" onclick="doSomething()" />
```