# event.target.innerHTML not returning current value

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I am trying to do data validation on an editable field using an `onchange` event trigger. When the event fires, I am passing the event. My function tries to display the `innerHTML` in an alert but it always returns null.

Here is my code:

```
<head>
<script>
   function chkchg(evt) {
     alert(evt.innerHTML);
   }
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
    <td><input class='patched' contenteditable='true' type='text' onchange='chkchg(event.target);' value='Yes'></td>
    <td><input class='excluded' contenteditable='true' type='text' onchange='chkchg(event.target);' value='No'></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
```

It seems pretty simple but I don't know what is wrong.

Comment: `innerHTML` returns the HTML between tags like `<div>HTML</div>`. You however are trying to get the `value`. [See this answer for that.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4173391/javascript-get-element-value)

Answer (score 0):

Try passing in only the event to the chkchg function and reference the target property inside of the function. But the real fix here is referencing the value property of the input instead of innerHTML:

```
<head>
 <script>
  function chkchg(evt) {
   alert(evt.target.value);
  }
 </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <table>
   <tr>
   <td><input class='patched' contenteditable='true' type='text'   onchange='chkchg(event);' value='Yes'></td>
   <td><input class='excluded' contenteditable='true' type='text' onchange='chkchg(event);' value='No'></td>
  </tr>
 </table>
```

Comment: I get the same results - a null alert.

Comment: Ok, you need to reference value of input since that is target of event. innerHTML would have worked if you were referencing the td

Comment: That was it! I need to access value instead of innerHTML. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want the value of the input, why not use `this.value`. And `innerHTML` won't work on input fields. you need to use `value`.

```
<script>
    function chkchg(evt) {
        alert(evt);
    }
</script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input class='patched' contenteditable='true' type='text' onchange='chkchg(this.value);' value='Yes'></td>
        <td>
            <input class='excluded' contenteditable='true' type='text' onchange='chkchg(this.value);' value='No'></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Or using `this`. You then can access other properties.

```
<input class='patched' id='patched' contenteditable='true' type='text' onchange='chkchg(this);' value='Yes'>

<script>
    function chkchg(evt) {
        alert(evt.id + " - " + evt.value);
    }
</script>
```