# Get element by name which has $key

Tags: javascript, php, html

### PHP

```
<input type="number"  min="0" max="500" value="" name="qty<?php echo $key ?>" id="<?php echo $key ?>" onChange="findTotal()" />
```

### JS

```
function findTotal() {
    var arr = document.getElementsByName('qty');
    ....
}
```

How do I get element by name which has `$key` inside?

Comment: `getElementById()`?

Comment: same as the way you specify in html.

i.e., var arr = document.getElementsByName('qty<?
     php echo $key ?>');

Comment: @JPKim it didnt work

Answer (score 0):

Let's say $key is 'x'. You could then use getElementbyID('x'), because echoing $key is the same as putting id="x".

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I see. you have series of rows with the different qty keys.

then try this.

in PHP:

```
<input type="number" min="0" max="500" value="" name="qty<?php echo $key ?>" id="<?php echo $key ?>" onChange="findTotal('qty<?php echo $key?>')" />
```

and in JS:

```
 function findTotal(key) {
    var arr = document.getElementsByName(key);
    ....
}
```

Comment: weird..it should work. I guess you have to check other part of the codes first. check the html out source if echo $key actually works. 
for example, if the key value is "abc", then the html look like this:

<input type="number" min="0" max="500" value="" name="qtyabc" id="abc" onChange="findTotal('qtyabc')" />

Answer (score 0):

You can assign `this`as your function params then you can call its name or id from your function when onchange event executed !!

```
//assign this
<input type="number"  min="0" max="500" value="" name="qty<?php echo $key ?>" id="<?php echo $key ?>" onChange="findTotal(this)" />

function findTotal(current) {
  var arr = current.name; // current.id for id
  alert(arr);    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your `name` is dynamic, you can not get the element by the `name` unless your JS has some way of knowing that dynamic `name` (such as if you have a list of them and are running them in a loop).

In your case, you may want to try using `data` attributes as outlined here:
[Mozzila - Using data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes)

You may also be able to take advantage of `this` as outlined in this answer:
[Javascript Get Element Value - Answer By yorick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4173391/javascript-get-element-value)

Let me know if this helps. I may be able to refine this answer if you can give some more information about your specific implementation.

Cheers!