# Grading calculator

Tags: javascript, html-helper

HI im a student and I programed this calculator for give a average for 3 grades yet I cant calculate/average my final grade, I wish for advance.Thanks
P.S I could find a way to post my HTML and my java so i put photos,sorry.
[picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AYLl9.png)[picture2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5thDo.png)

Comment: please read this if you're going to ask about homework https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: Provide HTML also

Comment: Where's the question? What problems have you encountered? What have you tried?

Comment: Provide HTML text not image

Comment: are you gonna submit your code as a  photo to your professor?

Comment: SO Isn't a place to get people to do things for you, this is a place to ask for help/direction in a problem. Read what @Isaac posted and try again.

Comment: The first three lines of your `calculator()` function have syntax errors. Also, the IDs you are referencing in your JS do not exist in the HTML shown in the picture. (A picture? Please don't do that. [Edit] your question and paste the HTML as text.)

Answer (score 0):

You got to match the id and get value `document.getElementById('homework').value`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function calculator() {
    var homework = parseFloat(document.getElementById('homework').value);
    var labs = parseFloat(document.getElementById('labs').value);
    var midterm = parseFloat(document.getElementById('midterm').value);
    var finals = parseFloat(document.getElementById('finals').value);

    var total = homework + labs + midterm + finals;

    var display = document.getElementById('outputDiv');
    display.innerHTML = 'Your Final Grade Is: ' + total;
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Hi i would like to edit my question. Where can I edit my question?

Comment: @SoichiroOkuyama end of your post, click Edit

Answer (score 0):

Read this link:

[Javascript Get Element Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4173391/javascript-get-element-value)

And edit your code to:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function calculator()
    {
        var grade1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('first').value);
        var grade2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('second').value);
        var grade3 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('thrid').value);
        var total = grade1 + grade2 + grade3;
        document.getElementById('outputDiv').innerHTML='Your Final Grade Is: ' +total;
    }

</script>
```