# Change value of target textbox using function in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create a function to change the value of targeting textbox but I can't figure out what's wrong with my code.

```
<form name="formcalc">
  <input type="text" value="1" name="A" >
  <input type="button" value="Change" onClick="change(A)">
  <br>
  <input type="text" value="2" name="B" >
  <input type="button" value="Change" onClick="change(B)">
</form>
<script>
function change(x) {
       document.formcalc.x.value = 3;
}
</script>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4173391/getting-dom-element-value-using-pure-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are sending the element directly to the function, below will work

```
function change(x) {
   x.value = 3;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to Add id attribute in input type=text and call them with

```
document.getElementById("nameId").innerHTML=yourdata...
```