# How can I console log my sum from the function below?

Tags: javascript, html

**I have been trying to display the sum with console.log, it seems not to be working.
Can anyone assist?**

```
var result = document.getElementById('result');
var firstNum = document.getElementById('number1');
var secondNum = document.getElementById('number2');

firstNum.addEventListener('keyup', sum);
secondNum.addEventListener('keyup', sum);

function sum(e){

    var mySum = firstNum + secondNum;
    console.log(mySum);
}
```

Comment: You need to: get the value, not the HTMLElement (`.value`), get it the moment the event listener fires, not globally once at start of evaluation, and convert to number, as inputs have string values.

Comment: firstNum and secondNum are html elements (inputs probably) you can't add inputs but only their `.values`s (if you convert them to numbers correctly)

Comment: 1. `firstNum` is an HTML element, not a value. You can't sum it. [Use `.value`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4173391/getting-dom-element-value-using-pure-javascript) 2. The result is a string, you need to [convert to a number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14496531/adding-two-numbers-concatenates-them-instead-of-calculating-the-sum).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `firstNum` and `secondNum` are input fields you would need to get the value of these inputs. Input values are string so you also would need to cast the values to numbers.

```
var result = document.getElementById('result');
var firstNum = document.getElementById('number1');
var secondNum = document.getElementById('number2');

firstNum.addEventListener('keyup', sum);
secondNum.addEventListener('keyup', sum);

function sum(e){

    var mySum = Number(firstNum.value) + Number(secondNum.value);
    console.log(mySum);
}
```